# Show directions using google map flutter package?

Tags: flutter, google-maps

I have an already saved map route as an encoded string in the database. I need to show
already saved route and the direction to the user in the google map using [google_maps_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter) package. Even in the google map is okey. There are options to draw the markers and poly lines using the package, but no option to enable direction(like go 300m and then turn left).

here is the code sample I tried, without direction

```
    GoogleMap(
       initialCameraPosition: _initialPosition,
       myLocationEnabled: true,
       trafficEnabled: true,
       markers: _markers,
       polylines: _polyline,
       cameraTargetBounds: _cameraTargetBounds,
)
```

using google map app we can do that(I'm using [map_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/map_launcher) package to do that like below), but only parsing origin and destination and it's the direction at that time, not the already planned and saved route.

```
mapLauncher.MapLauncher.showDirections(
      mapType: mapLauncher.MapType.google,
      origin: mapLauncher.Coords(origin!.latitude, origin.longitude),
      originTitle: 'Your Locations',
      destinationTitle: 'Destination Location',
      destination: mapLauncher.Coords(destination!.latitude, destination.longitude))
```

does anyone knows a way to achieve this? is it not possible?

Answer (score 1):

There is no FREE way to show directions using Google maps flutter package. You either use another map package or open google maps app (if you're not looking for a FREE way ignore and go all the way down).

**FREE WAY**

If you would like to open Google Maps app from your app you could do something like this.

- First set up your url String (what you will send to Google maps app so it knows what directions give):

  ```
  String url = 'https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=' +
        currentLocation.latitude.toString() +
        ',' +
        currentLocation.longitude.toString() +
        ' &destination=' +
        lat.toString() +
        ',' +
        lon.toString() +
        '&travelmode=driving&dir_action=navigate';

  _launchURL(url);
  ```

Where currentLocation means the user current location, and lat and lon means the destination.

- Then just launch that url, using an urlLauncher:

  ```
  void _launchURL(String url) async {
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }
  ```

**PAID WAY**

If you are super decided to get directions into your app, you can use [Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/overview).

Comment: Both of the methods doesn't support the directions for already saved and planned route (means with about methods route could change day to day based on the traffic. what i want is, show the already planned route with way points, it doesn't matter the traffic